# How do I prove the measurability of the $j$-th smallement element mapping function?

Tags: measure-theory, order-statistics

Related : [How do we formally define "j-th smallest element"?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2986748/how-do-we-formally-define-j-th-smallest-element)

Let $F_j:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a $j$-th smallest element picking function.

How do I prove that $F_j$ is Borel measurable?

I know how to prove it for the case $j=1$ and $j=n$, but I am not sure how to prove this for the case $1<j<n$.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Assume that there are three functions, $F_1,F_2,F_3$. The second smallest is
$$\min\{\max\{F_1,F_2\},\max\{F_1,F_3\},\max\{F_2,F_3\}\}.$$ Looks like you can handle that! Generalize by letting the "inner set" consist of maximums of subsets of $j$ functions.

Comment: After all, for you to be able to define "$j$th smallest", the set of functions must be finite. Therefore there are finitely many collections of exactly $j$ functions. Take the maximum of each collection (=measurable), and then the minimum of those maximums (= still measurable).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I just read your comments. It works. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fleshing out the comment so that the question won't get stuck in the unanswered list.

---

Let $\{f_1,f_2,\ldots,f_n\}$ be the collection of measurable functions, $f_i:\Bbb{R}^n\to\Bbb{R}$. Let $S$ be the collection of subsets of $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ that have exactly $j$ elements. Observe that $|S|=\binom nj$, so $S$ is a finite collection.

To each set $M\in S$ we can define the maximum
$$
f_M:\Bbb{R}^n\to\Bbb{R}, x\mapsto\max\{f_i(x)\mid i\in M\}.
$$
As a maximum of a finite set of measurable functions we can conclude that $f_M$ is measurable for each $M\in S$.

Your claim then follows from the observation that the function $F_j(x)$ picking $j$th smallest from the list $(f_1(x),f_2(x),\ldots,f_n(x))$ for all $x$, can be written as
$$
F_j=\min\{f_M\mid M \in S\}.
$$

As the minimum of a finite collection of measurable functions this is immediately seen to be measurable.